# JS heap out of memory for Angular testing

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs, angular-test

I have a memory issue I'm trying to figure out and I don't really know where to start. When I'm running tests, I get a JS heap issue and my tests will error out without ever running. My hunch is that it is being caused by a very large strings file that I use for internationalization. This is an inherited project so I'll outline what currently happens and maybe someone can help me figure out a way to make it better.

**In the main application**

A file `inject.en.js` is a 2.2MB `json` file containing translated strings for the application.

```
var INJECT_en = { ... };
```

To have it available as early as possible, it is included as a global `var` in the applications `index.html`

```
<script src="js/languages/hybrid.inject.en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It is then used to build up a global config object.

```
var windowJS =  new WindowService().nativeWindow;
var HybridInject = windowJS.HybridInject_en; // custom app strings
var INJECT = windowJS.INJECT_en;
var startInjector = _.merge(_.clone(HybridInject), _.clone(INJECT));

export const CONFIG: ConfigType = {
    ...
    strings: populateStrings(startInjector),
    ...

}
```

**For testing**

I'm using Jest for testing this application for a number of reasons. I tried a few things to set Jest up to have those files available in the same way when the `CONFIG` is build and I settled on the following for my `jestGlobalMocks.ts`.

I copied the files into a testing directory and converted them to `export` the object.

```
export const INJECT_en = { ... }
```

Then made them available to the `CONFIG` build by making them available on the window.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'HybridInject_en', {value: HybridInject_en});
Object.defineProperty(window, 'INJECT_en', {value: INJECT_en});
```

**The result**

When tests are run, I get the following output

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "jest/configs/inject.en.ts" as it exceeds the max of "500KB".



<--- Last few GCs --->



[208:0x37d62f0]    86678 ms: Scavenge 1384.7 (1422.5) -> 1383.8 (1423.0) MB, 11.5 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.143, current mu = 0.101) allocation failure 

[208:0x37d62f0]    86694 ms: Scavenge 1384.7 (1423.0) -> 1383.9 (1423.5) MB, 13.5 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.143, current mu = 0.101) allocation failure 

[208:0x37d62f0]    86710 ms: Scavenge 1384.9 (1423.5) -> 1384.2 (1424.0) MB, 13.5 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.143, current mu = 0.101) allocation failure 





<--- JS stacktrace --->



==== JS stack trace =========================================



    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x255fdc5dbe1d]

Security context: 0x0e1a9b79e6e1 <JSObject>

    1: SourceMapConsumer_allGeneratedPositionsFor [0x32dd014cb6a1] [/var/jenkins_home/workspace/base_jenkins-build/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:~178] [pc=0x255fdcb3491a](this=0x0319d2aa8031 <BasicSourceMapConsumer map = 0x68f75371d81>,aArgs=0x1954c0c022a9 <Object map = 0x68f75372671>)

    2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */...



FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

 1: 0x8daaa0 node::Abort() [node]

 2: 0x8daaec  [node]

 3: 0xad73ce v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]

 4: 0xad7604 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]

 5: 0xec4c32  [node]

 6: 0xec4d38 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [node]

 7: 0xed0e12 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]

 8: 0xed1744 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]

 9: 0xed43b1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]

10: 0xe9d834 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [node]

11: 0x113cf9e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]

12: 0x255fdc5dbe1d 

Aborted

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script section of your `package.json` you should increase the heap (example below but you'll need to adapt for your uses, i've never used jest)

```
"gulp": "node --max_old_space_size=2560 ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp",
"run-build": "npm run gulp",
"run-build-with-switches": "npm run gulp -- myspecialtarget"
```

The first line sets up a script that runs gulp with increased heap anytime you reference it with `npm run gulp`.
The second line will run the first script with no arguments (for gulp this means default target). 
The third line will run gulp with the argument `myspecialtarget`.

Answer (score 0):

I after struggling for a while i managed to fixed this issue by replacing all **^** by **~** from the all the dependencies in `package.json` file.

**Replace**

```
  "dependencies": {
     "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.0",
    ...

  },
```

**To**

```
  "dependencies": {
     "@agm/core": "~1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    ...

  },
```

I think this issue is because of conflict between different version of libraries.